# Slick slider animation slides over layer

Tags: jquery, animation, slick.js

I'm using slick slider, 
I want to make some effect on my slides, when click to next slide arrow. I want open my new slide like SlideInLeft effect but i would keep previous slide on position. So new slide will open to previous slide with z-index or how to do this ?

I can't figure out.

I think like that something;

```
  $('.hero-text-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
                    $('.slick-active .slItem').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('.slick-active .slItem').addClass('flink');
                });

                $('.hero-text-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
                   $('.slick-active .slItem').removeClass('flink');
                    $('.slick-active .slItem').addClass('hidden');

                });

              });
```

Here is i addClass (flink) to my current slide and give it to screen with slideInLeft effect but this time my previous slide go out from screen.